# Present a modal view from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios5, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I'm trying to migrate the data from a previous version to the actual data format. While the application does this, I want to present a view which displays a waiting message (or a progress, haven't decided yet...).

Currently I'm figuring out when to migrate in the method `AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and then I want to present that view modal. But it doesn't work at all.

I tried

```
[navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES]; // works in a way, but it's not modal and it navigates sideways
[navigationController presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES]; // does nothing.
```

I also searched this forum and found some answers regarding a TabViewController. I tried to apply that to my scenario and even tried:

```
[window addSubview:viewController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Which does exactly nothing. Any ideas?

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: Well ... I loaded a storyboard and did everything there (also the handling to load the original storyboard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you instantiate the window?

self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

Comment: No, I recently learned that the self.window variable is not prefilled by the system ... :/